# Printing with indenting every line

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a way in python to print something, say

`foo = "The Title of The Message\n\tThe first paragraph of the message"`
 
with a tab appended to each line, without modifiying my variable, (`foo` in this example) .

The result I want would be:

    `The Title of The Message
        The first paragraph of the message"`

I'm looking for something similar to when you do a `git log`, the message of the commit is always indented

Comment: What is the problem? Looks like you have the string you need.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi printing ```foo``` as is would give the result without an indentation at the beginning of each line. Notice how "The Title of The Message" has a \t behind it, and similarly on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of any builtins / standard ways of doing it, but you could do a single tab with [Prune's simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32662595/925478) (`print foo.replace('\n', '\n\t')`), or if you want it more general for any number of leading tabs:

```
>>> def print_indented(n, s):
...     """Print a string `s` indented with `n` tabs at each newline"""
...     for x in s.split('\n'):
...         print '\t'*n + x
...
>>> foo = "The Title of The Message\n\tThe first paragraph of the message"
>>> print_indented(1, foo)
        The Title of The Message
                The first paragraph of the message
>>> print_indented(2, foo)
                The Title of The Message
                        The first paragraph of the message
```

The `'\t'*n` bit repeats the tab character `n` times.

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done with the [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) module, specifically its [`indent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.indent) function.

Example:

```py
import textwrap


foo = "The Title of The Message\n\tThe first paragraph of the message"
print(textwrap.indent(foo, '\t'))
```

Output:

```
        The Title of The Message
                The first paragraph of the message
```

There is an optional `predicate` argument which can be used to control which lines are indented, e.g. you might want to ignore empty lines and whitespace-only lines to not add unnecessary extra spaces.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure what you expect here.  No, there isn't an automatic formatting tool to do this.  However, you can certainly copy the value and modify *that*, or print an in-line alteration.  For instance:

```
print foo.replace("\n", "\n\t")
```

string.replace returns an altered copy of the string.